# Expected value of 3 to the power of sum of 2 dice

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

Two dice are rolled and then 3 gets raised to the power of the sum of these two dice's values. What is the expected value of the expression.

**Solution**
The expected value of one die is $3.5$ and the expected value of their sum should be $7$, because the dice are independent. Thus, the expected value is $3^7$.

**Question**: Is this a correct solution?

Comment: No.  it is not generally true that $E[f(X)]=f\left(E[X]\right)$ for a random variable $X$.  This is already false for, say, $f(X)=X^2$.

Comment: No, it is not.  For a small example, notice that $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^2=3\neq 2^{1.5}$

Comment: As an aside... "*and the expected value of their sum should be $7$* **because the dice are independent**"  This has nothing to do with independence, it is true for dependent random variables as well that $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$

Comment: One nice thing about this example is that one can literally roll a pair of dice 100 times and compute the average value of 3 to the power of their sum; we will see for ourselves that the average is substantially larger than $3^7$.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach is to *take off your shoes*.

$\sum_{k=2}^{12} ~p(k)3^k$, where $p(k) =$ probability that $k$ was rolled.

If you get to the point where you accept that the above expression is accurate, then any alternative expression that does not result in the same *final computation* can't be correct.

Comment: I like the use of "take off your shoes."

Comment: What does "take off your shoes" mean ? I haven't come across it.

Comment: @trueblueanil it means to forgo **any** attempt  at elegance, and enumerate the answer by simply counting.  It is a metaphor for using both your fingers and toes to count (at least up to twenty).

Comment: Ok, thanks, couldn't find a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Following @user2661923 (and yes... my shoes are off), here's the distribution of dice sums:

[image: p(k)]

and here is the derived distribution:

[image: derived distribution]

...and the mean of the final distribution is: $33124$.

---

For those familiar with *Mathematica*:

```
q = TransformedDistribution[
   x + y, 
   {x \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}],
    y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}];

DiscretePlot[PDF[q, x], {x, 2, 12}]

z = TransformedDistribution[3^x, x \[Distributed] q];

Mean[z]
```

(* 33124 *)

```
DiscretePlot[{3^y, PDF[z, x^y]}, {y, 2, 12},
 Ticks -> {Table[{y, 3^y}, {y, 2, 12}], Automatic},
 PlotRange -> {{1, 12}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: I don't think placing the flag *inside* your answer (i.e. "Following @user...") works.  For example, I don't think that I got flagged.  Also, I never responded to the original query with a comment.  Therefore, if in such a situation you want to flag the person in my position, it seems that you would have to leave a comment following my answer.

Comment: Wasn't necessarily a flag but instead an acknowledgement, or "citation," such as it is.